# Anchor <a> alignment off in IE8?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, alignment, anchor

We have three anchor tags.  When all on one line they display correctly in IE8:

[image]

But when you separate the anchor tags onto separate lines for better code readability they do NOT appear correctly (there is a random extra "e" character and the alignment is off):

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Please post your HTML. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the 'dulplicate characters bug', this is usually caused by white space or comments in your code. Long time since ive seen this, thought it was ironed out in ie7. Obviously not.

Think the only fix was to remove the white space or comments.

Comment: Just did a quick google and found this, take a look at the first paragraph http://positioniseverything.net/explorer/dup-characters.html

Comment: That looks to be the case.  I fixed this by applying `display:inline` to my anchor tags per this link http://snipplr.com/view/11000/ie6-double-margin-bug--duplicate-characters-bug-fix-using-jquery/.  Thanks for the help!